# Extracting substrings from command output

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

How can i extract only the `kim`, `tin`, and `tintu` substrings from the  command output below.   The substrings can't be had by simply splitting on `-`. The `xxx` bits are strings which are specific operator, so I hashed them out.

```
> kubectl get pods
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-x-ram-kdm-xxxxx-ramkim-6b4c49f589-6hqcj       
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-x-ram-kdm-xxxxx-ramtin-8d49b4dc7-bmvck        
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-x-ram-kdm-xxxxx-ramtintu-69b8c5b689-64fxw
```

Sorry I could not add much info due to customer restriction .  I will describe the nature of the output. ram is the fixed name with concatenated with a string that need to be extracted. no of - are not fixed in each output line and no of letters are also not  fixed. in this example ram appeared as  -ram- . I need to extract only string that is concatenated with ram+'extract-string' no matter where ever it is appeared but surly it appears only once.

Comment: You'd need to clarify how those can be identified, is that the sequence of letters that follow the second occurrence of `ram`, is that the sequence of non-dash characters starting at position 36. Is that the 6th `-`-delimited field stripped of its first 3 characters?

Comment: You also need to clarify exactly what you want in the output - is it **just** the `kim`, `tin`, and `tintu` strings, or with the prefix too (`ram` in your examples - is that fixed or whatever happens to be in the 3rd - delimited field?), or with the remainder of the line too?

Comment: I can't believe this question got upvoted and is getting answers. There's vague requirements, vague input specification (are those chains of `x`s always the same length? can they contain `-`s`? etc.), no expected output, and no attempt from the OP to solve it themselves. And yet it had an upvote and so far has 4 answers.

Comment: Sorry I could not add much info due to restriction .  I will describe the nature of the output. ram is the fixed name with concatenated with a string that need to be extracted. no of - are not fixed in each output line and no of letters are also not  fixed. in this example ram appeared as  -ram- . I need to extract only string that is concatenated with ram+'extract-string' no matter where ever it is appeared but surly it appears only once.

Comment: You can add anything you like, just obfuscate it by using text that looks like your real data instead of sharing the real values. Please [edit] your question such that the sample input you provide matches the description you just gave, i.e. varying numbers of `-`s, varying numbers of `x`s, and add the expected output given that input as well as your own attempt to solve the problem so we can help you with that.

Comment: It's still not clear if you `need to extract only string that is concatenated with ram` because `ram appeared as -ram- ` and what you really need is to extract text associated with any prefix string that appears in the location that `ram` currently appears in, or if you always only want text associated with the one, specific prefix `ram`. If the former and the number of `-`s and other letters isn't fixed, how do we know where to find that prefix string in the data to match on it later in the line?

Comment: I need to extract only the string  after ram. yes there -ram- in the entire sting but we should ignore that one.

Comment: @NagDevineni you should edit your question and update it with the new info.   Comments are ephemeral, they can be deleted at any time.   Add a sample of the output you want **and** details of how the output is to be extracted, and how that relates to the string `ram`.   Also, if there is significant variation in the input data, you **need to show a representative sample of how that data varies**.   Obfuscate/anonymise it as required, but you need to show the variety of patterns.

Answer (score 3):

Update based on your comments, I think this will do what you want:

```
$ awk -F- '{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
      if ($i ~ "^ram.+") { sub("^ram","",$i); print $i} }
    }' kubectl.txt
kim
tin
tintu
```

In English: for each field of each input line, if the field value matches the regex `^ram.+` (begins with "ram" and followed by **at least one** more character) then use sub() to remove "ram" from the beginning of the field and print the field.

or in perl:

```
$ perl -F- -lne 'foreach (@F) { print $1 if (m/^ram(.+)/) }' kubectl.txt 
kim
tin
tintu
```

In English: for each field of each line, if the field matches the regex "^ram(.+)" then print the captured portion of the field matching the `(.+)` sub-expression (i.e. everything after "^ram").

NOTE: if more than one field in a line matches the pattern, then they will all be printed.  If you only want the first such field, use `next` to stop processing the current line and skip to the next:

```
awk -F- '{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
      if ($i ~ "^ram.+") { sub("^ram","",$i); print $i; next } }
    }' kubectl.txt
```

or

```
perl -F- -lne 'foreach (@F) { if (m/^ram(.+)/) { print $1; next } }' kubectl.txt
```

---

I'll leave my old answers below, because they might still be useful to other readers with similar questions:

I'm not sure exactly what you want as output, so here are some possibilities.  They all produce output only for lines where field 6 (`$6`) begins with the contents of field 3 (`"^" $3`).  All other lines are ignored.

`kubectl.txt` is a text file containing your sample `kubectl get pods` output:

A substring of field 6, from character 4 to end of the field:

```
$ awk -F- '$6 ~ "^" $3 { print substr($6,4) }' kubectl.txt 
kim
tin
tintu
```

Field 6 with the contents of field 3 removed from the beginning using `sub()`.  Unlike the example above, this isn't hard-coded to strip the first 3 characters, so works with $3 of any length.

```
$ awk -F- '$6 ~ "^" $3 { sub("^" $3,"",$6); print $6}' kubectl.txt 
kim
tin
tintu
```

The same same as above with fields 7 and 8 too, separated by spaces:

```
$ awk -F- '$6 ~ "^" $3 { sub("^" $3,"",$6); print $6, $7, $8}' kubectl.txt
kim 6b4c49f589 6hqcj
tin 8d49b4dc7 bmvck
tintu 69b8c5b689 64fxw
```

Same as above but with `-` delimiter.

```
$ awk -F- -vOFS=- '$6 ~ "^" $3 { sub("^" $3,"",$6); print $6, $7, $8}' kubectl.txt 
kim-6b4c49f589-6hqcj
tin-8d49b4dc7-bmvck
tintu-69b8c5b689-64fxw
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do it for any line length, providing you always want the word
occurring after the last 'ram' in the line:

```
sed 's/.*ram\(\w\+\).*/\1/' your_file
```

The ways it's working is as follows:

- I search for everything up until the last occurrence of 'ram' `.*ram`
- I remember the stuff in between the above using `\(` and `\)`
- In this case that would be one or more word characters `\w\+`
- Match the rest of the line `.*`
- Then replace with the remembered content `\1`

Once you've confirmed it does what you want, just add the `-i` if you want to
change the file directly:

```
sed -i 's/.*ram\(\w\+\).*/\1/' your_file
```

To be clear, the above will turn this:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-x-ram-kdm-xxxxx-ramkim-6b4c49f589-6hqcj       
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-x-ram-kdm-xxxxx-ramtin-8d49b4dc7-bmvck        
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-x-ram-kdm-xxxxx-ramtintu-69b8c5b689-64fxw
```

into this:

```
kim
tin
tintu
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to get are the `kim`, `tin` and `tintu` strings from the example in your post, you can do it using the following:

```bsh
cut -c 36- | sed "s/-.*//"
```

Here a couple example:

```bsh
echo "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-x-ram-kdm-xxxxx-ramtintu-69b8c5b689-64fxw" |  cut -c 36- | sed "s/-.*//"
```

output: `tintu`

For a file containing the input from your post:

```bsh
cat file |  cut -c 36- | sed "s/-.*//"
```

output:

```
kim
tin
tintu
```

It is probably obvious, but this will only work if the strings will always have `36` character before the wanted string.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` and `PCRE`

```
grep -Po '(?<=-ram)[[:lower:]]+(?=-)' data
```

Extract any sequence of one or more lowercase character only if they are preceded by the word `-ram` and followed by a `-`

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of which ever column  present below command will provide output

```
awk -F "-" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /kim|tin|tintu/){print substr($i,4)}}}' filename
```

output

```
kim
tin
tintu
```

Comment: I don't know if I understand the current question, but it does say "I need to extract only string that is concatenated with ram+'extract-string'" which seems to require that only lines with "ram" in them should be matched. They did not show any non-matching lines, which would be helpful to test against.